# Как подключить нестандартные шрифты на сайт?

Tags: html, css

Нужно чтобы работало в FF и Opera

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Юзай `@font-face`.
Вот [кроссбраузерный генератор](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator). Пользуюсь сам.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, можно использовать сервис google. [База шрифтов](http://www.google.com/webfonts).